# How to create a json object in jsp?

Tags: javascript, json, jsp

How to create a json object in jsp?

```
var jsonObj = {
    "firstname": "test",
    "lastName": "test",
    "email": "test",
    "mobile": "test",
    "place": "test",
    "country": "test"
};

alert(jsonObj.length);
```

This prints "undefined" for length.

---

```
var json = {"person":
    {
        "p1":
            {"home":
                {"address":0,
                "phoneNumber":0
                },
            "office":
                {"address":0,
                "phoneNumber":0
                }
            },

        "p2":
            {"home":
                {"address":0,
                "phoneNumber":0
                },
            "office":
                {"address":0,
                "phoneNumber":0
                }
            },

        "p3":
            {"home":
                {"address":0,
                "phoneNumber":0
                },
            "office":
                {"address":0,
                "phoneNumber":0
                }
            },
    },

    "msg":"People data"
} ;
```

Suppose this is my json object.
I want to run a loop and iterate through the values..

```
alert("json length = " + Object.keys( json ).length);   //2
alert("keys in json : " + Object.keys(json));   //person,msg

var people = json.person;   
var personLen = Object.keys( people ).length;   //3
```

Now I want to run a loop and get the values inside p1, p2, p3 ..

```
for(i=0; i<people; i++) {

    var person = people[i]; //but this doesnt work

}
```

How do I get these values using loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This prints "undefined" for length.

Because it doesn't have property named `length` and it is not an array which would have a built-in property `length`.

If you want to get the number of properties in this object then try

```
Object.keys( jsonObj ).length
```

Comment: But if we get it through an ajax call, we are able to use length. Why is that?

Comment: can you share what output you get as AJAX response?

Comment: @Ridhima sorry to say, but this is an entirely diff question now. First you asked `how to get the length of an object` and now you are asking `how to get the length of dynamic child objects`

Comment: Yes I know its a different question. Using Object.keys( jsonObj ).length solved the question I asked first and I accepted your answer for that. 

Now I need to know something more, so I have edited the question. Would be great if you can answer.

Answer (score 1):

There is no length property on Object

```
var jsonObj = {
    "firstname": "test",
    "lastName": "test",
    "email": "test",
    "mobile": "test",
    "place": "test",
    "country": "test"
};
// It will return an array of 6   elements['test','test','test','test','test','test']
var a =Object.keys(jsonObj) 
alert(a.length);
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/p4cpr9ed/)